# Verify Identity of Spawned Process

Tags: .net, security, signalr

I have a .NET program that will spawn processes that execute plugins. These plugins will communicate with the main process using SignalR. I'd like to verify the identity of the plugin making the SignalR calls to ensure data integrity. I thought of sharing a secret on the command line, but that's pretty easy to find. Is there a more secure way?

Comment: How do you host your solution?

Comment: It's a Windows command line application and the web server is self-hosted ASP.NET Core.

Comment: But where are you hosting it? On your own VM? On the cloud? On the PaaS component like Azure Web Apps? ...?